# Kivy button example closes immediately when testing

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to learn Kivy using their examples, however I'm having an issue. I'm using their button doc example:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button

def callback(instance):
    print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)

btn1 = Button(text='Hello world 1')
btn1.bind(on_press=callback)
btn2 = Button(text='Hello world 2')
btn2.bind(on_press=callback)
```

However, the program runs and immediately closes. I assumed maybe its tkinter, where the program runs on a constant loop and you need to add something at the end so it doesn't close, but I couldn't find anything on their docs about that.

To reiterate, I don't get any errors, the file just runs, I get a very brief pop up, and then it ends. I don't get an interface.

Comment: as I understand from tkinter, your buttons aren't being associated to a 'master' nor do you even have a master canvas to put your buttons on.  At least, that's what I get from the code above.  Have  a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm

Comment: I'm not using tkinter, I'm using Kivy

Comment: ah, then might the following help: https://likegeeks.com/kivy-tutorial/ ?  The theory still applies though.  your button isn't attached to an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, kivy need to loop for control all own functions. So we need a App class and have to return our layouts directly or layouts under Screen Manager. [In Kivy-Button documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html), **Kivy shows you only related part**. So there is a no any App class or loop for control.So program runs and closes immediately because app class doesn't loop window.

If you're beginner and trying to learn kivy from documentation, you need to figure how Kivy actually works and how documentation explain things. I'm sharing this code below for you, you need to understand add-remove widgets ,set layouts,... in kivy from documentations or search for full-code examples not part.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
class TestLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        but1 = Button(text='Button1')
        self.add_widget(but1)
        but2 = Button(text='Button2')
        self.add_widget(but2)
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestLayout()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

When you understand how it works, you should start to use [Screen Manager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) for easily create pages, send-get values (and many things) for your applications.I hope these helps you at the beginning. Good luck.